# RelativeLayout and margin?

Tags: android, android-layout

I added a `View` to my `RelativeLayout` and I set 300dp margin left
then I added another view but the second view is not affected by the margin of the first. Why ?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="use margin left view 1"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="not affected by margin view 2 "
        android:textSize="40sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have put them in a `RelativeLayout` in which you need to anchor the child views relative to each other.

So in this case you have to add the attribute `android:layout_toRightOf=´="@+id/text"` to your second `TextView`.

Whole layout will look like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="Some text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_toRightOf=="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="Some other text"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can read more about RelativeLayout here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are only apply the `marginLeft` to the first `TextView`, not both of them. If you want to apply the `marginLeft` to both `TextViews`, you could surround both of them with a `LinearLayout` and then give the `LinearLayout` a `marginLeft` of 300dp or you could give both `TextViews` a `marginLeft` of 300dp

Here is the code by wrapping both `TextViews` in a `LinearLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       //Other stuff here

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="300dp">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:text="use margin left view 1"
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="290dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:text="not affected by margin view 2 "
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    //Other stuff here
</RelativeLayout>
```

You could also just use the properties of a `RelativeLayout` to get the same desired results such as `alignLeft`.

Here is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
            android:text="use margin left view 1"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/text"
            android:text="not affected by margin view 2 "
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Other `RelativeLayout` attributes to try out can be found here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

and here is an example of some being used:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Answer (score 0):

The `RelativeLayout` is the container. It does not pass the layout parameter from one child to another automatically.

To make all children in the `RelativeLayout` have the same left margin then i would suggest to add the margin to the `RelativeLayout` itself instead of the `TextView`

So your code would be:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200p"
        android:text="text 1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="text 2"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use LinearLayout in this case. Don't forget to mention the orientation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:text="use margin left view 1"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:text="affected by margin view 2 "
    android:textSize="40sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```